# Predicting Manhattanhenge

Tags: date-and-time, code-request, astronomy

At the time of writing, Manhattanhenge is tonight in New York City ([ref 1](http://www.amnh.org/our-research/hayden-planetarium/resources/manhattanhenge/)), "an event during which the setting sun is aligned with the east–west streets of the main street grid of Manhattan, New York City." ([ref 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattanhenge))

Is there a way to predict future dates of Manhattanhenge for other years, or more generally creating your own for your home town? (ie. Sunset down main street of AnyTown, USA)

Thinking of *SunPosition* at *Sunset* for Lat, Long; but how to set it to up for matches direction needed for your hometown? (or Manhattan if replicating Manhattanhenge)

**EDIT**
Reducing scope of question from comments: The azimuth angles don't match on that date and time. If can understand the azimuth discrepancy I can figure out the rest. Thank you.

I tried the following code for today (7/11/2016) for Times Square, knowing it is Manhattanhenge, but the azimuth angle does not equal the azimuthal direction going along 42nd st.

```
TimesSquare = GeoPosition[{40.7589, -73.9851}] ;
Pt42nd1 = GeoPosition[{40.749467, -73.970835}];
Pt42nd2 = GeoPosition[{40.761835, -74.000741}];
SunPosition[TimesSquare, Sunset[TimesSquare, DateObject[{2016, 07, 11, 12, 0}]]]
GeoDirection[Pt42nd1, Pt42nd2]
```

Output:

```
{300.28°, -0.74°}
-61.4505°
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything - or is this a coding request?

Comment: Yes, thank you - it is more of a coding request. I couldn't figure out where to even start.

Comment: Try to make a table using `SunPosition` for the sun location along the horizon at sunset for each day.  Pick the right one.

Comment: Thank you, I tried for today for Times Square but could not make the angles equal. Edited the question with the code used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP, showing little or no effort of his own, is simply begging others to write code for him

Comment: Well, ok, you can vote. I did try, though, as I thought the short code I wrote would be the solution to NYC, but couldn't understand why the Azimuth angles were different. I'm not an expert in Mathematica, hence asking for help from the experts. Sorry to bother everyone and waste people's time. Vote to close. Vote to delete.

Comment: The code looks fine - the angle is only about a degree out. Probably the sun moves a degree in azimuth between Manhattanhenge (when the full solar disk is just above the horizon) and sunset (when the full solar disk disappears below the horizon).